# Why does elasticsearch raise elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ValidationException: You cannot write to a wildcard index.on pypy but not cpython?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pypy

I have [some code](https://github.com/domainaware/parsedmarc/blob/master/parsedmarc/elastic.py#L306) that saves data to Elasticsearch. It runs fine in Python 3.5.2 (cpython), but raises an exception when running on pypi3 6.0.0 (Python 3.5.3). Any ideas why?

```
File "/opt/venvs/parsedmarc/site-packages/parsedmarc/elastic.py", line 366, in save_forensic_report_to_elasticsearch
  forensic_doc.save()
File "/opt/venvs/parsedmarc/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 394, in save
  index=self._get_index(index),
File "/opt/venvs/parsedmarc/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 138, in _get_index
  raise ValidationException('You cannot write to a wildcard index.')
elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ValidationException: You cannot write to a wildcard index
```

Answer (score 5):

I have tried several combinations of swapping DocType for Document, adding or deleting class Index or class Meta. However, in any combination, the name of the index was left empty. Debugging proved that, and after a bit of tweaking, I got it to work.

This bit of code worked for me:

```
 class Index:
    # index = 'sample_index'
    name = 'sample_index'
```

Note that I haven't tried to use this with name only. Also, it worked with DocType, but it should work with new Document class as well.

Reference to [Sean's question at GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/953). The above solution is confirmed on the thread.
Keeping it in one place, previously mentioned link: [Document to replace DocType for newer versions of Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/Changelog.rst).

Answer (score 0):

We ran into similar issues, seems like elasticsearch_dsl renamed DocType to Document in their new version 6.2 what breaks backwards compatibility.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/Changelog.rst

Either fix your version to 6.1 or you have to update to the new Document type.